# XAML markup extensions design time

Tags: c#, translation

https://xamlmarkupextensions.codeplex.com/

I'm having a problem using the xamlmarkupextensions library. This library provides the opportunity to Bind values from a resource file (resx) to different controls. Now this works perfectly, but I don't want to use the resource file... I would like to use my own database.

So I made a new database and tried some stuff and got it working. The only problem is that the value is not visible in design time... Does anybody here knows how this could work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add your code, maybe the screenshots. As it stands, your question is incomplete.

Comment: Use `d:DataContext` and create some sample data in Blend.